# Cortana's not searching PC files...?

Tags: windows-10, windows-search, file-search, cortana

I have windows 10, btw.

I'm trying to search for files in my documents folder (not in OneDrive) using Cortana, but whatever I search, the only documents that show up after a while are ones on my OneDrive that are vaguely related. For example, I'm looking for a pdf titled "usermanual.pdf", which is on my PC, but Cortana can't find it. I don't even think she looks there.

I've been looking for a fix for weeks about this problem, and the only solution I could find is to re-index. I've indexed the entire C:, to no positive result.

Apologies if I haven't provided enough information.

Comment: Open `services.msc` from Win+R. Check if the Windows Search service is running.

Answer (score 3):

Cortana will not search all directories in PC by default, you need to configure Index for her, just like search feature.

[image]

In general, if we want to search a file rather than a system setting or feature, we use the search box in File Explorer.

Comment: Regarding your last comment, Vista and Windows 7 both did local file searches by default from the Start menu. It's no surprise users would expect that from 10.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to **Settings** > **Cortana** > **Permissions & History**. (Searching in Cortana for "Permissions & History" doesn't work, but that's a separate problem.)
2. Turn off **Cloud Search**.